# Javascript - How should I write a reusable method that waits for one of a set of events to occur?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm adapting to using Protractor as a UI automation framework, having used Selenium with Java, Ruby and Groovy extensively in the past. I'm new to Javascript so I'm not sure if some of my old tricks are transferrable.

One of the most useful things I came up with in Ruby and Groovy was a "multiwait" library that would allow me to wait for one of set of mutually exclusive events to occur. Given a map in which the keys are simple descriptions of events, and the values are chunks of executable code, the function would simply loop through each of the possible events, and when an event returned true, the function would return the key for that event. If none of the events returned true within a given timeout, an Exception would be thrown summarizing the events and the time that it waited for. There was also a special event, "nothing," for situations in which an action might give rise to a warning or error event if something was wrong with the data, but would usually elicit no response at all if the data was good. If "nothing" was one of the events, then instead of throwing an Exception at the end of the timeout, the function would return the key for the "nothing" event.

I am now trying to re-implement this method in Javascript, but I'm very new to the language and I'm not sure of the best way to go about it.

So I know that in Javascript I can store functions as variables. Should I be using functions as my event values in this Hash Table? Will they present any problems with scope, or should everything work as long as each function is able to see the variables that it uses?

If someone could run through a simple example with me that'd be very helpful. Let's say that I have a page object with a method called `getColor` which retrieves some information from the DOM. In this case let's say that it will always return the String `red`. I want to create a method in a separate file that will accept a Hash Table of events, something like this:

```
var WaitForEvent = require('../../waitForEvent');
var wait = new WaitForEvent();

function getColor() {
  return 'red';
}

var outcomes = {};
outcomes['Data accepted'] = function () { getColor() == 'green' };
outcomes['Data rejected'] = function () { getColor() == 'red' };

var result = wait.waitFor(outcomes);

expect(result).toBe('Data accepted');
```

So, that's a rough idea of how I want to set up the parameters for the method itself. Would functions like that work in this context? Could a waitForEvent function loop through the functions, testing each one to see which one returned `true` first, and then return the key describing the event that occurred? Or do I need to go about this in a different way?

Assuming it would work, what would it look like in the method itself, as I'm looping through the values of the Hash Table which are themselves nameless functions? What's the proper way to execute such a function and check what it returns?

One thing I'm already aware of in Selenium, which I'd like to avoid, is Selenium's `ExpectedConditions` with the `OR` condition chaining conditions together. I'd rather something more flexible than that.

Thanks!

Comment: yes this would work, but I am thinking that you would wait for some (user or browser) event to take place. So if this is the case you would need to recall `result = wait.waitFor(outcomes);` untill this event occurs or else add [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and run the `waitForOutcomes` in there

Comment: @NikosM. I definitely don't want `waitFor` to be called more than once for a given set of events. The idea is that `waitFor` will either use a default timeout value or an optional timeout parameter, and will loop over the possible events, testing and retesting them until one returns true or the timeout is reached, in which case an error will be thrown.

It's likely that the functions that define events will involve polling the browser state via Selenium calls, but my hope is that those will function just as they would in a Selenium test.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have (I'm translating these to es6):

```
const getColor = () => 'red';
outcomes['Data rejected'] = () => getColor() === 'red';
```

Now you can do:

```
let keys = Object.keys(outcomes).filter(k => outcomes[k]())
```

and `keys[0]` will be 'Data rejected' (instead of undefined)
I'm not sure if that answers your question though. To "wait" for it you would need to put it in a async function with some `setTimeouts`.